# Simple python string to list parser

Tags: python, parsing

So I came across [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372042/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-list-if-the-string-has-characters-for-a-group-of-ch#63372097) and I felt like it would be a cool thing to try and write a parser for since I always wanted to try it. So I present to you:

My first time writing a parser.

It converts strings like this:

```
"a,s,[c,f],[f,t], [[a,c],[d3,32]]"
```

into list objects

```
['a', 's', ['c', 'f'], ['f', 't'], [['a', 'c'], ['d3', '32']]]
```

Here is my code for now

```
def parseToList(string, cont=0):
  result = list()
  temp = ''
  i = cont
  while i < len(string):
    if string[i] == ',':
      if len(temp) and temp != ' ':
        result.append(temp)
      temp = ''
    elif string[i] == '[':
      res = parseToList(string, i+1)
      i = res[1]
      result.append(res[0])
    elif string[i] == ']':
      if len(temp) and temp != ' ':
        result.append(temp)
      return (result,i)
    else:
      temp += string[i]  
    i += 1
  if len(temp) and temp != ' ':
    result.append(temp)
  return (result, i)

def listParse(string):
  return parseToList(string)[0]

s = 'a,s,[c,f],[f,t], [[a,c],[d3,32]]'

print(s)
print(listParse(s))
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Something I should change?

Comment: Do you want a review of design or only of functionality?

Comment: @Hawk I would prefer the design since I know there really isn't much functionality. It only handles strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things that came to my mind:

---

### Bug

- `if temp != ' '` will not work when there are more than 1 consecutive spaces.
  To fix this, use `if not temp.isspace()` instead of comparing with a hard-coded string.
  For example, `s = 'a,   [b]'` will output `['a', ['b'], '   ']` for your current code.
- Your code outputs `['a', ' b']` for `a, b`. I'll assume that including the space is a feature and not a bug.

---

### Design

- Wrap the test code inside  `if __name__ == '__main__'`. This will prevent the code from being called when being imported from another module.
- Function names should preferably be lowercase. Change the CamelCase names to snake_case.
- In return statements, you need not enclose the items in a parenthesis if you are returning a tuple
- `result = list()` can be replaced with just `result = []`
- `if len(temp)` can be replaced with just `if temp`. The bool of empty values are `False` in python.

```py
res = parse_to_list(string, i + 1)
i = res[1]
result.append(res[0])
```

The above can be a bit simplified and can be made a bit more understandable.

```py
nested_list, i = parse_to_list(string, i + 1)
result.append(nested_list)
```

- Instead of using `string[i]`, you can declare a new element `char` which is equal to `string[i]`
  (This is just my personal preference)
- You can declare `parse_to_list` to inside `list_parse`. This will remove the need to pass `string` inside a recursion repeatedly, and will also make the inner function "private".
  (But this is also just my personal preference)

The final code should look something like this after applying the above:

```py
def list_parse(string):
    def parse_to_list(cont=0):
        result = []
        temp = ''
        i = cont

        while i < len(string):
            char = string[i]

            if char == ',':
                if temp and not temp.isspace():
                    result.append(temp)
                temp = ''

            elif char == '[':
                nested_list, i = parse_to_list(i + 1)
                result.append(nested_list)

            elif char == ']':
                if temp and not temp.isspace():
                    result.append(temp)
                return result, i

            else:
                temp += char

            i += 1

        if temp and not temp.isspace():
            result.append(temp)

        return result, i

    return parse_to_list()[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'a,s,[c,f],[f,t], [[a,c],[d3,32]]'

    print(list_parse(s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! I didn't know you can declare a function inside another. This is going to be super helpful! And yeah outputting `['a', ' b']` for `a, b` is intended.

Answer (score 1):

## Disclaimer

I am more of a Java dev, so please excuse my non-pythonesque ideas.

## Style review

Write code for someone else, not yourself (i.e. readable & understandable).

You have non-descriptive variable names.

- `i`: usually there is a better name for it, I would consider `i` viable in something like `for i in range`
- `temp`: what does temp represent? Already processed characters, so maybe call it `processed_chars` or something
- `result`, `res` - almost identical, very confusing. A single variable named `result` could be OK in a function, Martin Fowler uses it, although Uncle Bob despises it. You are doing parsing, so a probable alternative could be `parsed` or the like.
- `res`: why do you have this variable in the first place? Just use a tuple deconstruction into something more meaningful:

```py
parsed_list, new_i = parseToList(string, i+1)
```

I am not sure how python work, but maybe you could even replace `new_i` directly with `i`.

## Functionality review

You never fail. Weird. Are you sure you can always parse everything successfully? Even though this is a very simple and permissive language, probably not. Edge cases:

- `[`
- `[a,]`
- `[,a]`

## Design review

First of all I will create a grammar. It will ease my review and it should have simplified you your implementation:

```
list = "[" values "]"
# maybe values could be modified to accept dangling commas if you want
values = value { "," value }
value = list | string
string = <anything except "[" "]" "," trimmed (i.e. no leadind or trailing whitespace)>
```

Now we have a (context-free) grammar given by pseudo-EBNF. Usually lexer and parser are separate, but we don't really need special tokens, we could just use single characters as tokens. Usually a parser accepts a stream of tokens and outputs an AST. We don't need an AST, it could be directly interpreted as python values.
An alternative to using your whole `string` and `i` as a cursor is to use `string` as a stream of tokens, from which you take how many you want and return the rest (substring).

Now to implement a grammar, I would create a function for each non-terminal symbol (rule), f.e. `parse_list() -> []`, `parse_values() -> []`, `parse_value()`, `parse_string() -> str`. `parse()` would just call `parse_values()`. If you wrap these in a class. If you fail to match a symbol, you should raise an exception or let it known in your return value.

So I would suggest signatures either:

```py
class Parser:
    def parse(input: string) -> []:
        self.input = input
        parsed, unprocessed = self.parse_values(input)
        if unprocessed:
            # handle exception, maybe print
        return parsed


    def parse_list(cursor: int) -> []
        # Parameter: cursor index in `input`
        # raises exception on error
        # the whole input is stored in class field

    def parse_list(unprocessed: str) -> []
        # Parameter: the unprocessed input
        # raises exception on error

    def parse_list(unprocessed: str) -> ([], str)
        # Parameter: the unprocessed input
        # Returns: (parsedList, new_unprocessed) on success
        #          (None, unprocessed) on error
        # takes from unprocessed[0]
```

Example implementation draft:

```
def parse_list(unprocessed: str) -> ([], str):
    matched, unprocessed = match(unprocessed, '[')
    if not matched:
        return None, unprocessed

    values, unprocessed = parse_values()
    if values == None:
        return None, unprocessed

    matched, unprocessed = match(unprocessed, ']')
    if not matched:
        return None, unprocessed

    return values

def match(unprocessed: str, to_match: str) -> (bool, str):
    stripped = unprocessed.lstrip()
    if stripped.startswith(to_match):
        return True, stripped[to_match.len:]
    else:
        return False, unprocessed
```

If you keep a note of the remaining unprocessed input or the current cursor, you could report it when finding an error (f.e. in the raised exception)